# Display the time it takes each vagrant ansible task to complete

Tags: task, benchmarking, vagrant, provisioning, ansible

I'm converting a vagrant provisioner from shell to ansible and I was wondering if there's any option to show the actual time it takes to complete each task?

Ideally I want to benchmark the difference between installing multiple packages in yum using a shell: method and the in built yum: with_items method.  ATM I'm sitting here with a stop watch but I need accurate times for this.

Comment: Raath, please accept an answer if one suits you. Alternately, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I've solved for timing Ansible task durations by adding a [callback plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_plugins.html#callbacks). Callback plugins were designed to allow you to run your own arbitrary code based on events that happen in the context of an Ansible run.

[The plugin I use](https://github.com/jlafon/ansible-profile) is easily deployed by creating a callback_plugins directory and dropping a python script into it.

Here is an sample of the resulting output at the end of your playbook run:

```
PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
npm_install_foo | Install node dependencies via npm ------------------- 194.92s
gulp_build | Run Gulp to build ----------------------------------------- 89.99s
nodejs | Update npm ---------------------------------------------------- 26.96s
common | Update apt cache and upgrade base os packages ----------------- 17.78s
forever | Install forever (restarts Node.js if it fails) --------------- 16.84s
nodejs | Node.js | Install Node.js and npm ----------------------------- 15.11s
bower | Install bower --------------------------------------------------- 9.37s
Copy locally fetched repo to each instance ------------------------------ 8.03s
express | Express | Install Express ------------------------------------- 8.00s
```

Additionally, I prepend the shell command `time` to the ansible-playbook run. This nicely aggregates all of the individual task durations.

EDIT #1:

As of Ansible v2.0.0 this particular plugin ships with Ansible itself! Just add `callbacks_enabled = profile_tasks` to your `~/.ansible.cfg` file in the `[defaults]` section.

EDIT #2:
Since Ansible v2.1.5 `callback_whitelist` has been deprecated in favor of `callbacks_enabled`.

```
[defaults]
callbacks_enabled = profile_tasks
...
```

Comment: The `callback_whitelist = ...` line should go in the `[defaults]` section of `ansible.cfg'

Answer (score 3):

Ansible puts timestamps into its logs, so you could use that. You can switch this on using your ansible.cfg file:

```ini
[defaults]
log_path = ./ansible.log
```

You could also do something crude like this - create a playbook that looks like this:

```yaml
---
#
# Outputs a timestamp to the console
#
# Used for debugging/timing stuff.
#

- local_action: shell date +'%F %T'
  register: ts
  sudo: no

- name: Timestamp
  debug: msg="{{ ts.stdout }}"
```

Then `include` that wherever you want to output a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no performance logging by default.

But you can add your own **callback** listener to [ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/plugins/callbacks/log_plays.py). This call back will get notified on start and end of actions...

For complete example take a look at the [datadog](https://gist.github.com/alekstorm/6350729) plugin

Answer (score -2):

Simply prepend execution of the whole Ansible playbook with `time`.
Make sure that your `shell:` script is doing the same thing as `yum:` module, such as update cache, download files vs using locally cached, etc etc.

Benefit of using `yum:` is, among other things, Ansible can better handle failed installs as opposed to just blindly running your `shell:` command as a monolithic thing.

I think the difference will be extremely small(fractions of a second to 2-3 seconds). I imagine you'd need to run your benchmark dozens of times to have statistically accurate results.